# How to reference "Done" button in Sencha Touch datepickerfield

Tags: javascript, controller, sencha-touch

I need to fire an event when the user selects a date from the datepickerfield component (when they tap the built in "Done" button). I tried to make reference to the 'action' of the button, among other things, but no luck.

Any info on how to create a ref (or handler or listener) from the datepickerfield "Done" button would be greatly appreciated.

Below is part of my View:

```
     items:[{
                xtype:  'button',
                align:  'right',
                text:   'Mark all present',
                action: 'markAllPresent'
            },
            {
                xtype:   'datepickerfield',
                cls:    'pickAdate',
                align:  'left',
                label:  'Date',
                name:   'date',
                value:   new Date(),
                picker    : {
                    yearFrom: 2012,
                    toolbar : {
                        items : [
                            {
                                xtype:  'button',
                                ui:     'confirm',
                                text:   'Today',
                                align:  'right',
                                handler: function(button, event) {
                                    var picker = button.up('datepicker');
                                    picker.fireEvent('change', picker, Ext.DateExtras.clearTime(new Date()));
                                    //Today button , clear date
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                doneButton:{
                    action: 'dateDone'  //THIS DOES NOTHING ---------==============
                },
                listeners: {

                    change: function(picker, date) {
                        console.log(date);
                        var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                            model: 'App.model.NewDateModel',
                            id:'DateStore'
                        });
                        store.add(date);
                        store.setData(date);
                        store.sync();

                        this.fireEvent("newDatePicked", this); 
                        // **DOES NOT FIRE EVENT IN MY CONTROLLER================

                    }
                }
            }]
```

And my controller:

```
config: {
    control: {
        doneButton: {
            newDatePicked: 'newDatePicked'
        }
    },
    refs: {
        doneButton: 'button[action=dateDone]'
    }
},

newDatePicked: function(list, record) {
  .....
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [change](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.field.DatePicker-event-change) event in your controller,

```
control: {
    "datepickerfield[itemId=giveItemID]": {
        change: 'newDatePicked'
    }
},
```

You should give your datepickerfield an itemId and replace "giveItemID" with it.